# Clickable nested LinearLayout displaying AChartEngine dynamic graph

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, achartengine, clickable

I came across a post which exaplains that if I add `android:onClick="OnClickMethod"` to the `<LinearLayout>` in the XML file, and then in the JAVA file I add

```
    public void OnClickMethod(View v) {
    Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, START_INTENT);
}
```

It should make the LinearLayout clickable. Which it does. But, I have the following setup in my XML file:

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/myIcon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="xxx"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/myChart" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I add `android:OnClick="OnClickMethod"` to the `linearLayout1` it makes only the `TextView` and `Image` clickable. But ideally I want the graph to be clickable. I tried adding `android:OnClick="OnClickMethod"` to `myChart` LinearLayout and it did not make that area clickable at all.

BTW, the `myChart` LinearLayout displays AChartEngine dynamic plot. and I disabled the X and Y pans so the user cannot move the graph around (`renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false)`

Please exaplain to me what I am doing wrong? I want the plot to be clickable. I feel that I am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: I think charts in AChartEngine also respond to other gestures/touch events, so maybe see if you can disable all of those or just call `setClickable(false)` on the chart's GraphicalView. The idea is for the touch event to filter up to the LinearLayout parent.

Comment: You might also have to disable zoom on the AChartEngine, `renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add click interaction to your chart, you will have to enable the click interaction and add an `OnClickListener` on the chart view. You can see this working in [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) example, lines #156 to #176.

Comment: It helped. But right now the graph has the `onClickListener`, not the `LinearLayout`. Could I have achieved the exact same results have the `LinearLayou` being "clickable"?